# Why this regex is not matching the text string?

Tags: python, regex, jupyter-notebook

I have a python code as follows:

```
import re
string=" S/O: fathersName,other details,some other details."`
fathersName=re.match(r":.*?,",string).group(0)
```

The regex match is supposed to match the  `fatherName` part of the string, but I get a attributr error saying no mathces found

I even tried with `re.match(':',string)` and still I get 0 matches.

I think it is somehow related to : symbol, but I'm not sure.

I am using Jupyter Notebook

Comment: Use `re.search`.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

fathersName=re.search(r"S/O:\s*(.*?),",string).group(1)